# $f(x) = \lfloor \frac{1}{x}\rfloor$ Find $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$f(x) = \lfloor \frac{1}{x}\rfloor$ Find $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)$

1) $\lim_{x\to n^+}\lfloor \frac{1}{x}\rfloor$ so as $x$ approaches $n$ from above, $0 < x < 1$, $\lfloor \frac{1}{x}\rfloor = \frac{1}{n}$

2)$ \lim_{x\to n^-}\lfloor \frac{1}{x}\rfloor$ so as $x$ approaches $n$ from below, $-1 < x < 0$, $\lfloor \frac{1}{x}\rfloor = \frac{1}{n} - 1 = \frac{1}{-1} - 1 = -2$

So far that's my attempt at it.

Comment: If $x$ is very small, $1/x$ is very big; thus $\lfloor \frac 1 x\rfloor$ is *almost* as big as $1/x$.

Comment: Is the problem as $x\to 0$ or as $x\to n$?

Comment: It's as $x\to 0$

Answer (score 1):

You can use a very handful inequality to help you:
$$\forall y \in \mathbb R, y-1 \lt \lfloor y \rfloor \le y$$
Use it with $y=1/x$.

Comment: Would I be able to say this? $\lim_{y\to\infty+}\lfloor y\rfloor = \infty$ and  $\lim_{y\to\infty-}\lfloor y\rfloor = -\infty$